# Android: How to make notification bar look exactly similar when downloading from my server instead from android market

Tags: android

I am working with Android Jelly bean release.

When an application/file gets downloaded from my server, I want to give the users the same feeling as they get from downloading from an android market.

From the Notification builder API document of Andriod site , I can do something like below:

```
 Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
     .setContentTitle(Title)
     .setContentText(subject)
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
     .setProgress(int max, int progress, boolean indeterminate)
     .build();
```

What I am unable to figure out is how android market app gets "how much it takes to download" to download an app like "3 mins left" in the notification builder template.

If some one can help me to write an generic function which will return how much it takes to download the application after calculating the network speed and identify the time depending upon the application size, that will be of a great help.

Thanks for the help.